# Differentiable scalar fields question.

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, scalar-fields

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ be twice continuously differentiable scalar fields.
Which of the following statements is false? 
**A:** If $S$ is any simple piecewise-smooth surface with unit normal vector $\mathbf{n}$, then $\iint_S (\nabla\times\nabla f)\cdot\mathbf{n} \,dS=0$ 
**B:** If $S$ is the unit sphere with the outward pointing normal vector $\mathbf{n}$, then $\iint_S \nabla f\cdot\mathbf{n} \,dS=4\pi$ 
**C:** If the directional derivative of $f$ along the unit tangent vector of a simple piecewise-smooth curve $C$ is zero at every point on $\space\space\space\space\space C$, then $\int_C \nabla f\cdot d\mathbf{r}=0$ 
**D:** The vector field $\nabla f \times \nabla g$ is solenoidal

*What I know so far...* 
So, I believe statement **B** to be false since I know that $\iint_S dS=4\pi$ where $S$ is the unit sphere. Also, I know **D** to be true if $f$ and $g$ are twice continuously differentiable scalar fields - so that rules that out. My gut tells me **C** to be true since $C$ is zero at every point. It's from here I'm not sure which is false... any help would be great!

Comment: Did you compute $rot(\nabla f)$?

Answer (score 1):

For A: compute $\nabla\times \nabla f=rot(\nabla f)$ using the definitions.

For B: take a constant field and compute.

For C: use that $\frac{d f}{d \vec{v}}=\nabla f\cdot \vec{v}$ and that $\int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}=\int_C(\vec{F}\cdot \vec{T}) dr$, for vector fields $\vec{F}$.

Comment: You have to know the definitions in order to proceed. If it is not the case, you have to go look for them.